# How to fix an au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader

Tags: android

I have as an import the `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader`. Eclipse says that

> the import cannot be resolved

at: `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader`

> CSVReader cannot be resolved to a type

How to correct it? It is the only red marker of my code.

Comment: Done it! Thank you all for the space provided for my problem! For others new bees in Android like me, this item could be fixed by simply drag and drop the downloaded opencsv.jar into the libs folder! Jeeesus ... so simple!